# bracketsでカーソルの位置のあるタグのみを削除するショートカットや機能拡張はないですか？

Tags: adobe-brackets

bracketsでカーソルの位置のあるタグのみを削除するショートカットや機能拡張はないですか？

たとえば下の画像のような状況での「aタグを削除する」などです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]